How to receive OTP and continuous usage Java?
I have a problem, that the system reads exactly the last letter but not the letter that was just received so than I'll have an error while using this "expired" OTP. Only working with Thread.sleep and I don't know how to avoid this Thread.sleep and replace it by some wait.
Here is a version which works correctly but with Thread.sleep.
public class GmailAPI {
    public static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "src/resources/credentials.json";
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "triodos_email";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String USER_ID = "me"; //current emailId
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(GmailAPI.class);
    static Gmail service = null;

    public static String getOTPFromInbox() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        ListMessagesResponse listOfMessages = GmailAPI.getListOfMessages(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        Message firstEmailInList = GmailAPI.getParticularMessageFromListMessagesResponseBy(0, listOfMessages);
        return GmailAPI.getOTPFromMessageSnippet(Objects.requireNonNull(firstEmailInList));
    }

    public static GoogleCredentials getGoogleCredentials() throws IOException {
        try (InputStream credentialsStream = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)) {
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream)
                    .createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"));
            return credentials;
        }
    }


    public static ListMessagesResponse getListOfMessages(String credentialsFilePath) {
        log.info(String.format("Reading Gmail API credentials from: %s", credentialsFilePath));
        try {
            GoogleCredentials credentials = getGoogleCredentials();
            HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();

            log.info("Getting list of messages from Gmail inbox...");
            Gmail.Users.Messages.List list = service.users().messages().list(USER_ID);
            ListMessagesResponse listMessagesResponse = list.execute();
            if (listMessagesResponse.getMessages().size() == 0) {
                log.error("Empty list of messages. Check GmailAPI.getListOfMessages()");
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            return listMessagesResponse;
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            log.error(String.format("Exception was thrown in GmailAPI.getListOfMessages(): %s", e));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Message getParticularMessageFromListMessagesResponseBy(Integer messageSequenceNumber, ListMessagesResponse listOfMessages) {
        String messageId = listOfMessages.getMessages().get(messageSequenceNumber).getId();
        try {
            log.info(String.format("Getting %d message from the <listOfMessages>...", messageSequenceNumber));
            Message message = service.users().messages().get(USER_ID, messageId).execute();
            return message;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(String.format("IOException was thrown in GmailAPI.getParticularMessageFromListMessagesResponse(): %s", e));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String getOTPFromMessageSnippet(Message message) {
        String regEx = ":";
        log.info("Getting OTP from message snippet...");
        log.info(String.format("Splitting email body snippet string by '%s'", regEx));
        //check validity of OTP (if it contains letters or not enough digits)
        String body = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(message.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getParts().get(0).getBody().getData()));
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(body);
        Elements otpElements = doc.select(".email-otp strong");
        String otp = otpElements.text();
        if (otp.length() != 6 || !otp.matches("\\d+")) {
            log.error(String.format("Provided OTP invalid and contains either letters or short digits sequence: %s", otp));
            log.error("Check GmailAPI.getOTPFromMessageSnippet() method ");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return otp;
    }
}


To avoid using Thread.sleep in your Java code and replace it with a more reliable wait mechanism, you can use a combination of a loop with a timeout and a condition to check for new messages.

If possible, use an event-driven approach where the system notifies you of new emails
